# Pegar o último registro por data de um historico de lançamentos em mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Preciso pegar a última situação de uma doação em determinado período.
Preciso agrupar por doação e por situação.
Somar por situação e ordenar doações por situação, pegando apenas a última.

```
Tabela LoteRetornoDoacao
Campos: id,dtBaixa,situacaoDoacao,vrTotalLote,num

Tablela Doacao
Campos: id, situacaoDoacao(atual),vrDoacao,idOperadorResponsavel

Tabela Operador
Campos:id, nome,codigo

Tabela DoacaoLoteRetorno
Campos:id, idDoacao,idLoteRetorno

Tabela LoteDoacao
Campos:id, idPartDoador

 Tabela Participante(doador)
 Campos:id,nome,cod
```

Preciso pegar a última situação da doação em um determinado período.
Já tentei isso e não funcionou, pega o valor máximo da data, mas mistura os outros campos:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
(CASE 
WHEN lrd.situacaoDoacao=0 THEN "Aberto"
WHEN lrd.situacaoDoacao=1 THEN "Recebido" 
WHEN lrd.situacaoDoacao=2 THEN "Devolvido" 
WHEN lrd.situacaoDoacao=3 THEN "Cancelado" 
WHEN lrd.situacaoDoacao=4 THEN "Confirmado" 
WHEN lrd.situacaoDoacao=5 THEN "Coleta"
ELSE "n" END)AS situacaoLoteRetorno,
lrd.situacaoDoacao,lrd.id,d.situacaoDoacao AS situacaoAtual,d.vr,partDoador.nome,d.codbarras
FROM Doacao d
LEFT JOIN DoacaoLoteRetorno dlr ON dlr.idDoacao=d.id
LEFT JOIN LoteRectoDoacao lrd ON lrd.id=dlr.idLoteRetornoDoacao
LEFT JOIN LoteDoacao ld ON d.idLoteDoacao=ld.id
LEFT JOIN Participante partDoador ON partDoador.id=ld.idPartDoador
GROUP BY dlr.idDoacao HAVING MAX(lrd.dtbaixa) ORDER BY lrd.dtBaixa DESC;
```

Segue modelo dos relatórios que preciso fazer.
[image: Agrupado]
[image: Detalhado]

Nem essa simples consulta retorno correto.

```
   SELECT  DISTINCT lrd.dtBaixa,dlr.idDoacao FROM LoteRetornoDoacao lrd
LEFT JOIN DoacaoLoteRetorno dlr ON lrd.id=dlr.idLoteRetornoDoacao
GROUP BY idDoacao ORDER BY lrd.dtBaixa DESC;
```

O que tem de errado? Acho que é a mania de achar que será filtrado como no excel.... srsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera vou deixar aqui para documentar o fórum.

Não vou deixar a consulta inteira,porque o objetivo é pegar um registro atendendo o quesito de maior data.

Logo a primeira coisa a fazer é uma query ordenando por data DESC.
Depois ao agrupar, o mysql, automaticamente pega o primeiro registro.
Exemplo com a tabela LoteColetaDoacao

```
   SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT lcd.*,dlc.idDoacao FROM LoteColetaDoacao lcd
LEFT JOIN DoacaoLoteColeta dlc ON dlc.idLoteColetaDoacao=lcd.id
ORDER BY lcd.dtColeta DESC)a
GROUP BY a.idDoacao;
```

Espero ter contribuído.